# CSS box-shadow in Firefox showing faint top border/shadow

Tags: html, css

I've set up an example which illustrates my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/XZeYK/5/

If you view this in Chrome, it's fine.  Firefox, however, adds an unwanted border to the top of the #navigation element. I can get rid of it by setting a negative spread radius, but this then screws up my rounded corners.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Monty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi actually its due to **box-shadow** as you defined so i just reduced the **blur value** of your box-shadow property and its working fine now.

**CSS**

```
.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px -1px gray;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px -1px gray;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px -1px gray;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=2, Direction=135, Color='#808080')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=2, Direction=135, Color='#808080');
}
```

i hope this will help you see the demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/XZeYK/18/

And there are five values of **box-shadow** property as we can define :-

AS Example : `-moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;`

1. The horizontal offset of the shadow, positive means the shadow will be on the right of the box, a negative offset will put the shadow on the left of the box.
2. The vertical offset of the shadow, a negative one means the box-shadow will be above the box, a positive one means the shadow will be below the box.
3. The blur radius (optional), if set to 0 the shadow will be sharp, the higher the number, the more blurred it will be.
4. The spread radius (optional), positive values increase the size of the shadow, negative values decrease the size. Default is 0 (the shadow is same size as blur).
5. Color

Comment: Its still showing a top shadow on navigation & left shadow is totally shifted to right as you make it "0"

Comment: please check the updated answer with reason why that problem was coming @SVS

Comment: @ShailenderArora its killing the shadow effect.

Comment: @SVS i think here is our moto is to give the solutions of problems and give the idea why the problem has came so i think some times we give the near by the problem but not exact the but person should understand why problem has came so i think its clear why problem was come your answer is also fine and mine answer is i think also rest of we have given a idea so now its upon to the vp how he can play with tricks and all......

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XZeYK/15/

Change this to shadow class:

```
box-shadow: 1px 4px 4px -1px gray;
```

And i think there is no need of mozilla or webkit related CSS.

Comment: thanks SVS - as I thought, some tweaking was required. See my own answer for my final css.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up going with the following for the .shadow class:

```
box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px -2px gray;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px -2px gray;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px -2px gray;
... <IE specific rules>...
```

The -moz and -webkit extensions are required to support old versions.  The box-sizing messed with my actual app so I've left them as they are (so ommitted those rules).

I'll mark both as accepted as you both helped me out.

Thanks,
Monty